# Why do links to duplicate question automatically redirect to the duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, front-page, anonymous-user

I've noticed the following several times lately: A question closed as a duplicate is shown on the front page* like this, which is perfectly normal.

[image]

However, when I click the link, it's automagically redirected to the duplicate question. That is, by clicking the link: [Obtain 3-D matrix from multiplication of one 1-D matrix and one 2-D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457301/obtain-3-d-matrix-from-multiplication-of-one-1-d-matrix-and-one-2-d-matrix) I'm taken to [bsxfun implementation in matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807960/bsxfun-implementation-in-matrix-multiplication) without getting any notice.

My first guess was that it had been deleted after the front page was loaded, but that's not the case, as I've tried to refresh the front page, and it's still there. I'm assuming this is because the question is deleted, but I haven't been able to verify that yet.

Is this by design? Can anyone explain what is going on?

*Not really the front page, but this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/some-tag (I'm not sure what we call that page).

Comment: FWIW adding [?noredirect=whatever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457301/obtain-3-d-matrix-from-multiplication-of-one-1-d-matrix-and-one-2-d-matrix?noredirect=whatever) to question URL cancels redirect even for anonymous users (I just tested that)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question was not ever deleted. I'm assuming you were trying to access the question while **not logged in**, as anonymous users get automatically redirected to the duplicate target when trying to access questions closed as duplicates with no answers. For regular users, it will display the question with a duplicate notice like normal.

Comment: I didn't think of that, and yes... You're absolutely correct. Is that true for duplicate questions that does have answers too? Sometimes the duplicates have valuable, sometimes better, answers.

Comment: If there is an answer, it doesn't redirect. Only 0 answer questions are automatically redirected for anon users.

Comment: I'm logged in, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/28802529/1530938, automatically redirects me to the parent of the duplicate when I use the address-bar link