# Multiple duplicates - Can there be only one parent for duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question arose when I came across [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf?rq=1) question that is marked as duplicate. Following the link one finds a duplicate question ([A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277134/abusive-aggressive-users-taking-it-outside-of-stack-overflow)) leading to one "real" question and yet another duplicate ([B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf)). As if it wasn't confusing enough to be redirected to a question that is already somewhat worthless since it's a duplicate, clicking on B shows that it is a duplicate of...A.

I think it would be nice to have all duplicate questions simply refer to **one** parent and not redirecting to yet another duplicate or, even worse, mentioning each other. The more often similar questions get asked, the worse it could get, making it necessary to click through many questions until one finally finds the original question. Or is this meant to be a feature, so that one finds as many different responses as possible on the way?

Also, I was wondering if the redirection away from duplicate questions to the original for anonymous users also works for multiple duplicates. As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285853/why-do-links-to-duplicate-question-automatically-redirect-to-the-duplicate), when a user is not logged and the question has no answers, he is redirected to the original question. Has anybody seen a question tree like this? I'd be very interested in that, just for curiosity's sake. :)

**EDIT**

I just came across [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254710/is-there-a-benefit-to-closing-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-more-than-one-questio) discussion where the merits of having multiple redirections to other questions are mentioned. Still, I think that several links should only contain "original" questions, not more duplicates. Or would the updating process when the linked question changes its status be a problem?

Comment: Hm, odd, such circular duplicate references should be prevented by the system actually. However, there was some reopening and reclosing in both questions around that time, my guess is that A was voted to be closed as dupe of B, then B was closed as dupe of A, then A was closed as dupe of C - with mentioning B from the earlier vote in the banner.

Comment: Oh, so is the question just being mentioned? Because to me it looks like both are actual references to each other, I can't really tell the difference.

Comment: That's my guess. Multiple dupe links happen when there are multiple close votes with different targets. Even when a binding vote (by a moderator or gold badge holder) is cast, the links from earlier votes are shown - regardless whether the closer agrees with them or not.